# web2py rocket or Apache

Tags: apache, web2py

Web2py states in the home page 'including fast multi-threaded web server' and I have seen text that says the rocket server performs as well as Apache. Web2py also claims to set security as high priority.

So why do people recommend that rocket not be used in production? What are the disadvantages? If the answer is handling a lot of traffic, what might this be?

(I am looking at switching a Django application to web2py, and if for a small application I could use the rocket server it would simplify the initial transition.)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason people advise against Rocket in production is that it has few config / customization options.  With Apache or nginx or whatever, you have an endless supply of pluggable modules or built-in capabilities for security, caching, rewrites, logging, tuning, threading, error handling ... many diverse capabilities.  Rocket is more of just a good, basic web server with just a few of those options.

We use the Rocket server all the time in development environments -- it works very well in a low load, functionality-centric environment.  However we replace it with Apache by the time we reach security and load testing environments because we need several capabilities Apache provides / Rocket doesn't.

There is nothing wrong with Rocket.  It would probably be fine in a low-load production environment. If you ever decide you do need options Rocket doesn't have, change your choice of web server then.